# Вставить текст с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть кусок кода вида:

```
<p><strong>не важный текст</strong></p>    
<p><strong>нужный текст</strong></p>
<p><strong>не важный текст</strong></p>
```

Нужно после `<p>` с нужным текстом вставить есть еще один тег

, желательно с помощью регулярного выражения , у `<p>` есть вариативность со `style=""` и без

Comment: используйте функцию preg_replace().

Comment: вопрос скорее состоит в подборе самого регулярного выражения, функции которые нужно использовать я знаю

Comment: @Тимофей Семенюк подробнее опишите задачу.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin 
Есть заполненное описание товара в теге `<p><strong>Габаритные размеры (мм) (ШхГхВ): 1000х1000х1000</strong></p>`,после этого нужно вставить еще некоторый текст

Comment: На каком этапе отрисовки страницы текст должен вставляться? И какой источник у этого текста?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin на сервере рендерится , текст из бд

Comment: Тогда может вам не регулярки всё-же нужны, ведь у вас один источник данных и отрисовывается одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти `тэг <p> с любыми аттрибутами`, заменить на `то что нашли + дополнительный текст`:

```
$ php -r "echo preg_replace('/(<p[^>]*>)/', '\$1foo', '<p><strong>текст</strong></p>') . PHP_EOL;"
<p>foo<strong>текст</strong></p>
```

Comment: Почти , но проблема в том что таких тегов множество и уникального по отношению к другим только его содержание `Габаритные размеры (мм) (ШхГхВ): 1000х1000х1000`

Comment: значит это `/(<p[^>]*>)/` поменяйте на `/(<p[^>]*>)(уникальный-текст-детектор)/`. и этот же текст допишите во втором аргументе как `$2`. а ещё лучше обновите вопрос, т.к. сейчас его постановка никак не отражает этих ваших нюансов.